# Header view of UICollectionView keeps duplicating on scroll - How to create fixed (non-sticky), single collection view header?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, xcode10, uicollectionreusableview

I wanted to implement a view hierarchy like the following so that the ENTIRE view would be scrollable:

UIScrollView

- Image View
- Collection view

But a lot of people on here have said that it is better to use the header that comes along with the collection view. I've done that but now I have a new problem: as I scroll the collection view, any configurations I've done to the header cell in the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind function is duplicating (Eg: If I programmatically create a new view in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind function, this view will keep creating as I scroll)

I kind of get that this is happening because I'm dequeuing the header using dequeueReusableSupplementaryView. But I've tried searching on Apple docs and there are no other codes I can use to instantiate the header view without making it reusable.

Is there any way I can create a view controller as described above without using UICollectionView?

I've tried setting the number of sections to 1 hoping that it would only be reused ONCE but it doesn't work.

Edit: Also tried setting header size using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayouta and using UICollectionView instead of UIViewController and UICollectionViewDataSource etc.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView 
{
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            guard
                let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(
                    ofKind: kind,
                    withReuseIdentifier: "DiscoverHeader",
                    for: indexPath) as? DiscoverHeader
                else {
                    fatalError("Invalid view type")
            }

            // Rotating arrow image
            headerView.arrowImg.transform = headerView.arrowImg.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi/0.67)

            return headerView
        default:
            assert(false, "Invalid element type")
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you given the height of headerView?

Answer (score 0):

**Why not `UIImageView` and `UICollectionView` inside `UIScrollView`?**

You can definitely create a `UIScrollView` and add an `UIImageView` and a `UICollectionView` in it.

But that won't work as expected. This is because you're embedding a `scrollView(UICollectionView)` inside another `scrollView`. `Scrolling` the `collectionView` vertically will hamper the `scrolling` of the outer `scrollView`.

**Solution:**

Try giving the `height` of the `header view` using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout's` method,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 100.0) //give the height as per your requirement...
}
```

Also, set the `contentMode` of `imageView` as `Aspect Fit / Aspect Fill`.

Comment: Hi sorry, I guess I should've included it in my post that I've already programmatically set the header size using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and also set the imageView as Aspect Fill :(

Comment: Kindly add the screenshot of what you’re getting as the output.